# Python: how to get external boundaries from different polygons?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe that looks like the following

```
gdf.head()
    ID                                   geometry
0   1   MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.09835 42.35912, -71.09834 ...
1   2   MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.09692 42.35695, -71.09695 ...
2   3   MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.09355 42.35838, -71.09342 ...
3   26  MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.08526 42.36222, -71.08530 ...
4   28  MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.08578 42.36134, -71.08593 ...

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
gdf.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

I would like to create a unique polygon from the external boundaries of the small polygons.

And create a polygon like this

[image]

Comment: Convex Hull perhaps, if GeoPandas has such a thing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: `unary_union` on polygons you want to have within and then `convex_hull`.